# jquery .data() returns TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined in the console

Tags: jquery, jquery-data

I just can not wrap my head around on why this happens. In here it works as I think it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/TD2Yp/5/

The console brings `Object {filetype: "first"}` as a first log. But under my demo link:

http://beta.us.lt/demo/ where I do exactly the same in the console:

`$("#types").data("filetype")` - works as it brings back the filetype, but:

```
$("#types").data() brings:
```

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

Still not sure what is the difference between these two different contexts or how I could check what data holds the element under the demo link.

Comment: It works in the fiddle because the `latest` is currently 1.10.2, while you're using 1.3.2 in your `/demo/`. And, the [`.data()` overload](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data) you're trying to use was added with jQuery 1.4.0. Before that, the 1st argument wasn't optional. So, you'll need to use a newer version of jQuery, like in the fiddle, to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using very old version of [jQuery 1.3.2](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js)

Read [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

> In jQuery 1.4.3 setting an element's data object with .data(obj)
>   extends the data previously stored with that element. jQuery itself
>   uses the .data() method to save information under the names 'events'
>   and 'handle', and also reserves any data name starting with an
>   underscore ('_') for internal use.

---

> Prior to jQuery 1.4.3 (starting in jQuery 1.4) the .data() method
>   completely replaced all data, instead of just extending the data
>   object. If you are using third-party plugins it may not be advisable
>   to completely replace the element's data object, since plugins may
>   have also set data.

---

Upgrade your jQuery version to use it .